# Angular js How to get data rom controller to html template?

Tags: angularjs

I am working in angularjs and trying to get data from api to my html template.When user will click on anchor tag then data will load from api to html template.

This is anchor tag html

```
 <a href="#/myConatct" ng-click="side.getMyContacts();">Contacts</a>
```

In app.js i have called myContacts html and controller.

```
.state('myContacts', {  
            url: '/myContacts', 
            views: {
            'TopMenuBar': { templateUrl: 'views/menu.html',controller: 'MenuCtrl' },            'MainContent': { templateUrl: 'views/myContacts.html',controller: 'contactCtrl' }                     
            }               
            })
```

In service app factroy i am getting data from api.

```
service.getMyContacts = function(){
            var config = { headers:  {
                    'X-Auth-Token': $cookieStore.get('token')
                }
            };
            return $http.get(baseURL + '/allcontacts' ,  config);
        };
```

Then in sidebar controler i have called this function.

```
function sideCtrl($scope, $state, DataService, $cookieStore, $rootScope){
        var side = this;
side.myContacts = [];
        side.getMyContacts = getMyContacts;
        function getMyContacts(){   
            DataService.getMyContacts().success(function (data) {
                side.myContacts = data.results;
                 alert(data.results);
            });
        } 
}
```

I have also created a controller file.

```
app.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', '$location', 'DataService', '$cookieStore', function ($scope,$http, $rootScope, $location, DataService, $cookieStore) {

        $scope.getMyContacts = function(){
            var config = { headers:  {
                    'X-Auth-Token': $cookieStore.get('token')
                }
            };
            return $scope.getContactsList = $http.get(baseURL + '/allcontacts' ,  config);
       };

}]);
```

Now i am trying to get the json response data in myContacts.html file. But not loading html file it showing response data in alert.

Answer (score 0):

You've spelled `myContact` wrong in your `anchor` tag

```
<a href="#/myContact"">Contacts</a>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', '$location', 'DataService', '$cookieStore', function ($scope,$http, $rootScope, $location, DataService, $cookieStore) {

        $scope.getMyContacts = function(){
            var config = { headers:  {
                    'X-Auth-Token': $cookieStore.get('token')
                }
            };
            DataService.getMyContacts().success(function (data) {
               $scope.myContacts = data.results;
            });
       };

}]);
```

And then bind `$scope.myContacts` to something on your HTML.

**Note** A better way of doing this would be to define a resolve function in your state:

```
.state('myContacts', {  
            url: '/myContacts', 
            views: {
            'TopMenuBar': { 
               templateUrl: 'views/menu.html',
               controller: 'MenuCtrl'
            },
           'MainContent': { 
                templateUrl: 'views/myContacts.html',
                controller: 'contactCtrl' }                     
            },
            resolve: {
              contactData: function(DataService) {
                 DataService.getMyContacts().success(function (data) {
                return data.results;
              });
             }
            }
           })
```

And then in your controller, inject the data like so:

```
 app.controller('contactCtrl', function(contactData) {....})
```